# Picker not displaying previous selection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I was following [this](https://codemilltech.com/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker/) tutorial on a Bindable Picker for Xamarin Forms. I made it all the way through the tutorial, however I can't get the previous pick to display once I leave and come back to my settings page.

**Settings.cs**

```
public static double DistancePreferences 
{
    get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(DistancePreferences), 32.2); }
    set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(DistancePreferences), value); }
}
```

**DistanceItem Class**

```
public class DistanceItem
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public double Kilometers { get; set; }

    public static List<DistanceItem> All
    {
        get 
        {
            return new List<DistanceItem>
            {
                new DistanceItem { Display="1 mile", Kilometers=1.6 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="2 miles", Kilometers=3.2 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="5 miles", Kilometers=8.0 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="10 miles", Kilometers=16.1 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="20 miles", Kilometers=32.2 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="50 miles", Kilometers=80.5 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="100 miles", Kilometers=160.9 }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Picker from **SettingsPage.xaml**

```
<Picker x:Name="disPicker" ItemsSource="{x:Static distance:DistanceItem.All}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Display}" SelectedItem="{Binding DistanceSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**SettingsViewModel.xaml**

```
public DistanceItem DistanceSelection 
{ 
    get 
    {
        var distance = Settings.DistancePreferences;
        var item = DistanceItem.All.Find(x => x.Kilometers.Equals(Settings.DistancePreferences));
        return item;
    } 
    set 
    {
        // Saving the km from the selection for later 
        Settings.DistancePreferences = value.Kilometers;
    }
}
```

Here is the picker in action on my iOS sim. 
[image]

When I leave to another page in my app, and return to the Settings page, this is what I see. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important difference between your code and the code in your tutorial is that the code in the tutorial creates a single collection for All, and returns that each time the getter is called. Your code creates a new collection each time the getter is called.

Change your implementation of DistanceItem.All to something like:

```
private static List<DistanceItem> _all;
public static List<DistanceItem> All
{
    get 
    {
        if (_all == null)
        {
            _all = new List<DistanceItem>
            {
                new DistanceItem { Display="1 mile", Kilometers=1.6 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="2 miles", Kilometers=3.2 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="5 miles", Kilometers=8.0 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="10 miles", Kilometers=16.1 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="20 miles", Kilometers=32.2 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="50 miles", Kilometers=80.5 },
                new DistanceItem { Display="100 miles", Kilometers=160.9 }
            };
        }
        return _all;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that DistanceSelection returns an object from the same collection that is displayed by the Picker from its ItemsSource binding, rather than an object that has the same values but from a different collection.